# Edit multiple related tables on ASP.net MVC w/Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'll open with the statement that I am very new to .net and MVC so please bear with me. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and learning as I go.

Essentially - I have a .net MVC database-first project connected to a SQL db.  I used scaffolding to create 4 models - 
(Survey_Header_Response) - base survey information, identifies which survey a respondent gets
(Survey_Question) holds a unique list of the questions for all surveys and provides the actual question text,
(Survey_Response) lists of all the questions in the survey identified in (Survey_Response_Header) and will hold the value of each answer on post,
(Response_Values) - holds a list of possible responses for each of the different questions in each survey . Information on these is as follows:

Note - models are scaffolded, so even if I change them, they change back on db update.
Survey_Response_Header model:

```
public partial class Survey_Response
{
    public Survey_Response()
    {
        this.Response_Values = new HashSet<Response_Values>();
    }

    public int Survey_Response_RecID { get; set; }
    public int Survey_RecID { get; set; }
    public int Survey_Question_RecID { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Responded { get; set; }
    public int Contact_RecID { get; set; }
    public int Company_RecID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date_Sent { get; set; }
    public bool Responded { get; set; }
    public string Survey_Qtr { get; set; }
    public System.Guid Respondent_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Survey_Detail Survey_Detail { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey_Question Survey_Question { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Response_Values> Response_Values { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey_Response_Header Survey_Response_Header { get; set; }
}
```

Survey_Question:

```
public partial class Survey_Question
{
    public Survey_Question()
    {
        this.Survey_Cat_SubCat = new HashSet<Survey_Cat_SubCat>();
        this.Survey_Detail = new HashSet<Survey_Detail>();
        this.Response_Values = new HashSet<Response_Values>();
        this.Survey_Response = new HashSet<Survey_Response>();
    }

    public int Survey_Question_RecID { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public bool Inactive_Flag { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date_Created { get; set; }
    public string Created_By { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date_Updated { get; set; }
    public string Updated_By { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Survey_Cat_SubCat> Survey_Cat_SubCat { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Survey_Detail> Survey_Detail { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Response_Values> Response_Values { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Survey_Response> Survey_Response { get; set; }
}
```

Survey Response:

```
public Survey_Response()
    {
        this.Response_Values = new HashSet<Response_Values>();
    }

    public int Survey_Response_RecID { get; set; }
    public int Survey_RecID { get; set; }
    public int Survey_Question_RecID { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Responded { get; set; }
    public int Contact_RecID { get; set; }
    public int Company_RecID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date_Sent { get; set; }
    public bool Responded { get; set; }
    public string Survey_Qtr { get; set; }
    public System.Guid Respondent_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Survey_Detail Survey_Detail { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey_Question Survey_Question { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Response_Values> Response_Values { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey_Response_Header Survey_Response_Header { get; set; }
}
```

Response_Values:

```
public partial class Response_Values
{
    public Response_Values()
    {
        this.Survey_Response = new HashSet<Survey_Response>();
    }

    public int Survey_RecID { get; set; }
    public int Survey_Question_RecID { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int Question_Type_RecID { get; set; }
    public string Value_Label { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Created { get; set; }
    public string Created_By { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Updated { get; set; }
    public string Updated_By { get; set; }
    public int Response_Value_RecID { get; set; }

    public virtual Question_Type Question_Type { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey_Question Survey_Question { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey_Detail Survey_Detail { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Survey_Response> Survey_Response { get; set; }
}
```

}

There is a many-to-many relationship between the Response_Values & Survey_Response tables through the use of a pure-join table not shown here.

ViewModels: (See edit below)

ResponseData (intended to hold Survey_Response data and reference related tables)

I apologize for the length of this question - I'm new at this so my coding is probably messy and my explanation long.  Any help provided is much appreciated and will help me learn!

Edit:

Thanks for your reply. I understand where you're coming from, and I've attempted to build the controller but when I try to populate the ResponseData viewModel that contains the ICollection Survey_Response with data, I get an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List CustomerExperienceSurveyWeb.Models.Survey_Response' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection CustomerExperienceSurveyWeb.ViewModels.SurveyResponseVM'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Here's the relevant part of my controller code:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    //Survey_Response_Header survey = db.Survey_Response_Header.Find(id);


    var survey = db.Survey_Response_Header
        .Include(i => i.Survey_Response)
        .Where(i => i.Responded_ID == id)
        .Select(i => new
        {
            ViewModel = new ResponseData
            {
                Responded_ID = i.Responded_ID,
                Company_RecID = i.Company_RecID,
                Contact = i.Contact,
                Contact_RecID = i.Contact_RecID,
                Date_Responsed = i.Date_Responsed,
                Date_Sent = i.Date_Sent,
                Responded = i.Responded,
                Survey_Qtr = i.Survey_Qtr,
                Survey_RecID = i.Survey_RecID,
                SurveyResponse = i.Survey_Response.ToList() <<--- This is where the error shows
            }
        })
        .Single();
```

Updated ResponseData viewModel:

```
public partial class ResponseData
{
public ResponseData()
{
    this.SurveyResponse = new List<SurveyResponseVM>();
}

public System.Guid Responded_ID { get; set; }
public int Survey_RecID { get; set; }
public System.DateTime Date_Sent { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Responsed { get; set; }
public bool Responded { get; set; }
public int Contact_RecID { get; set; }
public int Company_RecID { get; set; }
public string Survey_Qtr { get; set; }

public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<SurveyResponseVM> SurveyResponse { get; set; }
}
```

Referenced SurveyResponseVM viewModel which is throwing the error:

```
public partial class SurveyResponseVM
{
public SurveyResponseVM()
{
    this.Response_Values = new List<ValueData>();
}

public int Survey_Response_RecID { get; set; }
public int Survey_RecID { get; set; }
public int Survey_Question_RecID { get; set; }
public string Response { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Responded { get; set; }
public int Contact_RecID { get; set; }
public int Company_RecID { get; set; }
public System.DateTime Date_Sent { get; set; }
public bool Responded { get; set; }
public string Survey_Qtr { get; set; }
public System.Guid Respondent_ID { get; set; }

public virtual Survey_Detail Survey_Detail { get; set; }
public virtual Survey_Question Survey_Question { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ValueData> Response_Values { get; set; }
public virtual Survey_Response_Header Survey_Response_Header { get; set; }
}
```

I know this means I'm not populating the ICollection part of the viewmodel correctly but I can't seem to figure out how it's supposed to be done. I've done days of research on the internet and I either don't know the right question to ask or I'm completely missing it. Any help you can give me is VERY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So the controller is essentially responsible for populating a model and pass this model to a view for rendering, there doesn't need to correspond to a database table.

The way I normally tackle this is to look at what the function is being performed, in this case survey and create a SurveyController. In here you will have a bunch of actions that correspond to views that are responsible for retrieving the correct data from the database, populating a model and then passing the model to the view for rendering.

So if you wanted to display a list of questions, you may do something like this (apologies if this contains errors, no VS atm):

```
public class SurveyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SurveyModel(); // This would contain any properties, like questions and their valid responses
        return View(model);
    }
}

public class SurveyModel
{
    public IList<SurveyQuestionModel> Questions { get; set; }
}
```